# One to many in Entity Framework using fluent mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Im trying to do a one-to-many map by using fluent api.
This is my classes

```
    public class Product : EntityBase
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.ProductArticles = new List<ProductArticle>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ReportText1 { get; set; }
    public string ReportText2 { get; set; }
    public bool Standard { get; set; }
    public int ProductGroupId { get; set; }
    public decimal? Surcharge1 { get; set; }
    public decimal? Surcharge2 { get; set; }
    public decimal? Surcharge3 { get; set; }
    public decimal? Surcharge4 { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceIn { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceOut { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceArtisanIn { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceArtisanOut { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceTotalIn { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceTotalOut { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceTotalOutVat { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceAdjustment { get; set; }
    public bool Calculate { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductGroupId")]
    public virtual ProductGroup ProductGroup { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductArticle> ProductArticles { get; set; }
}

public class ProductArticle : EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductArticleId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public decimal Qty { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceIn { get; set; }
    public bool Primary { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
}
```

Now i want from single Product include all ProductArticles

This is my mapping

```
    public class ProductMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(p => p.ProductId);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Product");
        this.HasMany(p => p.ProductArticles)
            .WithOptional()
            .Map(p => p.MapKey("ProductId").ToTable("ProductArticle"));
    }
```

But it doesnt work.. Please help :)

Comment: it doesnt work.... What exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - by convention EF treats property with name equal to `Id` or `EntityTypeName` + `Id` is a primary key. So, you don't need to configure that manually.

Second - if you don't want table names to be plural, just remove that convention from your context instead of providing table name for each entity mapping:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

And last - EF smart enough to define foreign keys which have names like `RelatedEntityTypeName` + `Id`. So, you don't need any fluent configurations here.

Comment: The problem with the conventions is that it all became more complicated to understand what is going on. If one extra line of code makes ir more explicit it is well worth.

Comment: @Marco conventions is a problem only when you have little knowledge about tool you are using. Google for **convention over configuration**. And I hope you'll stop specifying mappings for `Id` as a key property and `User` as a table name for `User` entity. Also each big project has it's own conventions. E.g. tables in database are named with `tbl` prefix. Instead of specifying table name for 100 tables normally you will use convention which developers know about. I can tell more about conventions, but try google yourself

Comment: I don't need to Google, I've been working in IT for over 10 years now, and I went past all the very verbose xml configurations files to no configuration at all, and all I am saying is that full convention is bad and it only works well in the beginning, as soon as you start adding more people to a project where a lot of conventions were created, that's when the issues start happening. So no, full convention over configuration is bad.

Comment: And just for the record, I did not say convention over configuration, I said full convention with no configuration ;)

Comment: @Marco I also have seen projects which were paid per line of code. Configuring everything manually when all default conventions worked well is the way guys coded there :) Obvious things should not be coded. If all things are obvious, nothing should be coded unless you are paid for each line.

Comment: I really doubt that, you don't seem to be older than 35 and the pay/per line of code is something that was lost in the early 90's, unless you were programming when you were around 10's :P  Well yeah, obvious things, and as I said before I'm against FULL convention, not the general use of conventions.

Comment: @Marco try to look wider. It's good skill for developers:) Hints: 1) systems from 90's have to be rewritten. 2) some guys in India still payed per line of code (or at least they are taught to write more code then required). It's good that you are only one against FULL conventions, so I'm ok with your personal preferences.

Comment: Only one against full conventions?! I don't really know the kind of people you're working with my friend but thankfully I'm not the only one I know who thinks this way. Perhaps you're the kind of developer that name variables, methods and classes the shorter you can to avoid writing a few more characters even if it becomes more messy to understand the whole thing later on... ah OK, as you say think wider, that way you can charge for a complete rewrite of the system cause nobody will know about your messy conventions... makes sense :)

Comment: I'm working on this proj, where I'm the one deciding the techs to be used. I've used NHibernate for a good few years and yes with a lot of full conventions too, but for this projec I choose EF instead and tried to avoid as many conventions as I possible, leaving in what is really obvious, and the reason, is simple. I was hired as a contractor, and the guys here don't know NHibernate/EF so I must ensure that when I leave the guys that are going to be working with what I did, can do it so without trying to process all the conventions that exist everywhere..Be professional and think wider.

Comment: @Marco I name variables according to the length of context they are used in. One letter for short lambdas. Good descriptive names for class fields. I'm that kind of developer. Thus you are speaking about short variables names length, you are probably stick to some 'good' length like 10-20 characters. I suggest you to think about each case individually instead of applying single rule for all cases. Same for conventions

Comment: @Marco and your last comment just proved my thoughts. Avoiding full conventions in case developers will not know EF is like avoiding lambdas in case developers will not know C#. You are applying specific case to all occasions. And I was right in my first comment - avoiding full EF conventions makes sense only *"when you have little knowledge about tool you are using"*. Specific cases should be handled separately. In your case I would start with explaining conventions to team. That team needed EF knowledge anyway - with conventions or without them.

Comment: Even if the team did know EF I would still avoid the use of some of the conventions just so things are more clear. At this stage I get your point and you surely get mine, thanks for your input and as I last recommendation please read: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/165649/is-convention-over-configuration-not-violating-basic-programming-principles